# Convert string to json using gson in jsp

Tags: json, string, jsp, gson

I have a very simple json in a string:

```
{"username" : "a", "active" : 0}
```

I would like to convert this string into a json object of some sort. I just need to get the value of username using jsp. I have gson set up if that helps.

Thanks in advance for any help,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a java class for storing your JSON, something like:

```
package com.onabai;

public class User {
    public String username = "";
    public int active = 0;
}
```

and then parsing the JSON from the JSP would be:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ page import="com.google.gson.Gson" %>
<%@ page import="com.onabai.User" %>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Powered by Zafu: OnaBai</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
    String json = "{\"username\" : \"a\", \"active\" : 0}";
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    User user = gson.fromJson(json, User.class);
    out.println("username:" + user.username);
%>
</body>
</html>
```

*EDIT:* If you only need the `username` you might define `User` as:

```
package com.onabai;

public class User {
    public String username = "";
}
```

having access only to `username`.

Comment: OP wanted only the username.

Comment: Edited for including an alternative where only has access to `username`

Comment: That works perfectly. Thanks very much for your help. I found similar answers online but this was by far the most simple and easy to understand. Thank you, just what I needed.